# Datepicker does not work after AJAX Call

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui-datepicker

I got a DatePicker that works just fine until AJAX call is made.

Any idea?

```
?><select onChange="Contract_PropertyDetails();" class="element select medium" id="contract_property" name="contract_property" width="300" style="width: 300px">  
<option value="0" >Select property</option>
```

Contract_PropertyDetails(); is my AJAX Function.

```
function Contract_PropertyDetails() {

var cp = document.getElementById('contract_property').value;
var companyid = document.getElementById('id_company').value;
var url = "incl_list_properties_contract.php?Company="+ companyid + "&cp="+cp;
url = encodeURI(url);

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    Contract=new XMLHttpRequest();

  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    Contract=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  Contract.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (Contract.readyState===4 && Contract.status===200) {
      document.getElementById("DETAILS_OF_LESSEE").innerHTML=Contract.responseText;
    }
  };

  Contract.open("GET",url,true);
  Contract.send();
}
```

DETAILS_OF_LESSEE is my DIV where the result is displayed.

withing the incl_list_properties_contract.php I got additional form to the field for the date picker.

```
<input type="text" id="Datepicker1" >
```

And here is the function within the Index.php

```
$(function() {
  $("#Datepicker1").datepicker("destroy");

    $( "#Datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth:true,
        changeYear:true
    }); 
});
```

I noticed that if the field for the date picker is outside the AJAX response, a level before the call. The following DIV is being automatically added and the date picker works fine.

[ui-datepicker-div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxTk1.png)
However if the input text fields is withing the response of the AJAX function so obviously is not on the page yet- thus at the first time the DIV does not exist.

So the question is how to execute the Date-picker withing the AJAX function when the Response is send and DIV content updated. ??

Awaiting reply please.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, the date picker plugin can't modify elements which don't exist when the code executes.  You have to initialize the plugin after adding the element to the page.

This would be done in the callback for the AJAX call.  Perhaps something as simple as this:

```
Contract.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (Contract.readyState===4 && Contract.status===200) {
        document.getElementById("DETAILS_OF_LESSEE").innerHTML=Contract.responseText;
        $( "#Datepicker1" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth:true,
            changeYear:true
        }); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi David, nope, I just tried your solution. Still the DIV for the DatePicker is not generated, and the datepicker does not work.

Comment: @RafalKanabus: Can you provide more information about the problem?  If you're re-using the `id`, that would cause it to fail.  If the code is executing when the element isn't on the page, that would cause it to fail.  Other problems could exist as well.  When you debug this, where/how *specifically* does it fail?  What is the state of the target DOM element?  Does the jQuery selector find anything at all?  You're going to have to debug this to see what's happening.

Comment: Well, the ID is unique; you just gave me an idea and I have moved the AJAX script from the bottom of the page (index.php) to the file it self incl_list_properties_contract.php), just after the input text field. It looks like this now: [code] 'Date from <input id="Datepicker1" type="text"  > 

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
 $( "#Datepicker1" ).datepicker({
  changeMonth:true,
  changeYear:true
 }); 
});
</script> But it did not make any difference; still does not work.

Comment: The only difference is that when it is through AJAX response does not work; otherwise it works perfect.

Comment: @RafalKanabus: I don't see what moving the code is going to do, that just seems like a random shot in the dark.  The concept itself is straightforward enough, you add the element to the DOM and then run the JavaScript to initialize the plugin on that element.  You're going to have to use your debugger here to find out how it's failing, I can't do that for you.  I can help explain what you find.

Comment: Thanks, in deed it was like a shot in the dark; well I will check and keep you posted. Thanks for help